# Keeping the value of a signature after running a predicate/ function?

Tags: alloy

I have been working on a project using Alloy, I have created a simple add function and what I don't know is how to make sure that the signature keeps it's value after the run:

example:

```
one sig c1,c2 extends Customer{}

run{
c1 = Create_customer[]
c2 = add_node[c1,node]
}
```

if you know more about this or have any related documentation or examples, I would be grateful.

Comment: Can you clarify? For example, include a full Alloy model, and say in very concrete terms (values of Alloy relations) what you want to achieve.

Comment: @AleksandarMilicevic I can explain better cause my model is a bit all over the place. To start with I have for example a customer that has a "set of nodes", then at a future state I would like to add another node to his set !! And since I can't override the same customer using Alloy !! I create this second Customer who is equal to the first Customer but with a "node" added !! And from this point on I would like to make sure that this second Customer was well created and only work with him !! ...

Comment: @AleksandarMilicevic !! I hope u can understand me better now !! cause i'm in need to understand how does it work after running the function !! will Alloy automatically preserve the value or what happens ?? I am confused !!

Comment: I think there's a confusion there. Alloy doesn't preserve anything between two runs. If you want to define an execution over several state, then you simply need to declare a "state" signature and define a mapping between those state and the changing values (in your case customers).
You can then use instance projection over this state signature to view the set of customers at a given state.

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni .. that is exactly what i'm in need of.. but I have never seen this anywhere .. so plz if u have some kind of links/ Documentation / Examples I'd be grateful

Comment: The Alloy Analyzer is packed with examples. Just open the tool and go on File > open Sample Models.  All the models in the Algorithms folder define executions using this concept of ordered states

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni ..it's weird.. cause in the version I have the folder is empty !!

Comment: weird indeed, simple google searched allowed me to find those slides. might be helpful to help you understand how to model behaviours : http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/tutorials/day-course/s4_dynamic.pdf

Comment: @LoïcGammaitoni .. exactly the ones I found !! thought the sample models contained different examples !! thank u for ur help anyway !!

Comment: yes it does contain different examples, maybe by opening the jar as an archive you will find them

Comment: The examples in "File -> Open Sample Models" come from https://github.com/kaptoxic/alloy/tree/master/extra/models